# How do I use abuild inside of a Distrobox container?

Tags: container, alpine-linux, apk-tools

I want to use Alpine inside of a Distrobox container using the [alpine-toolbox-edge](https://quay.io/repository/toolbx-images/alpine-toolbox?tab=tags&tag=latest) image and do various tasks involving the `abuild` program. I followed the instructions in the ["Creating an Alpine package" article](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/w/index.php?title=Creating_an_Alpine_package&oldid=23946), but I quickly ran into an issue where `$ abuild checksum` gave me a permission denied error despite that I had added myself to the abuild group, changed owner of the `/var/cache/distfiles` directory, and logged out and back in. As such, I decided to check what groups I'm in and noticed that the list looked like this:

```
$USER nobody nobody nobody nobody nobody nobody nobody
```

(where `$USER` is my actual username, not `$USER` verbatim)

As such, it seems like I haven't actually been added to the abuild group. I then tried the alternative command listed in the article, `# chmod a+w /var/cache/distfiles`. This made `$ abuild checksum` execute fine, but when I went on to run `$ abuild -r` to build the package I got the following error: `abuild-apk: User neboula is not a member of group abuild`, which is where I'm at now.

How can I set up a Distrobox container where `abuild` actually can abuild Alpine APK packages?

Comment: https://github.com/89luca89/distrobox/issues/997

I had exactly the same issue today.